# How to get the current custom view name of my SharePoint List

Tags: view, external-list

I am using the following JQuery to get the current name of the View for External SharePoint list.

```
var ctx = GetCurrentCtx();
var listName =ctx.ListTitle; 
var currentView =  $('[id*=\'ListTitleViewSelectorMenu\'] span:first').text();
```

My issue is, If the name of the current view is too long, it gets cut off while displaying in breadcrumb. Now when I am passing the value of my current view using  Request.Querystring, the value gets trimmed.

How can I resolve this issue in order to get the complete name of my view?

Answer (score 2):

### SharePoint 2013

For determining current List View the following properties of `ContextInfo` structure could be used:

- `view` - returns the current View Id
- `viewTitle` - returns the current View title

> viewTitle is not available in SharePoint 2010

Example:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("PrintContextInfo");   
function PrintContextInfo()   
{   
   var ctx = GetCurrentCtx();
   console.log(ctx.viewTitle); 
}
```

Comment: I happened to need this as well, I tried running GetCurrentCtx() but I am getting a null. I currently have it in a $(document).ready function... Am i on the right track?

Comment: Since SharePoint provides its own mechanism for page loading via _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames array,  it  is recommended to place the call for that code inside specified array.

Comment: I still get a null context, when I change it to "new SP.ClientContext.get_current();" it will return a context however there is no viewTitle property.

Comment: The answer has been updated,indeed, viewTitle property does not exists in SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

I got the view name passing the GUID of my view as following,

```
var listName =ctx.ListTitle;   
var currentViewGuid = ctx.view;
var url = $(location).attr('href');
var customurl = L_Menu_BaseUrl + '/_layouts/CustomRibbon/ExportList.aspx?list=' + listName + '&amp;url=' + url + '&amp;viewguid=' + currentViewGuid;
```

In my page load,

```
 public string viewguid;
 public string url;
 public string list;

 list = Request.QueryString["list"];              
 url = Request.QueryString["url"];
 viewguid = Request.QueryString["viewguid"];

 currentSPSite = new SPSite(url);
 SPWeb currentSPWeb = currentSPSite.OpenWeb();
 SPList currentList = currentSPWeb.Lists[list];
 SPView custView = currentList.GetView(new Guid(viewguid));
 view = custView.Title;
```