# Get the current view name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, list-view

In javascript, i need to know the current view.
I found this post but in 2010 it doesn't work:
[How to get the current custom view name of my SharePoint List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83611/how-to-get-the-current-custom-view-name-of-my-sharepoint-list)
When i do context.view, it's undefined.

Here is the complete code in the navigate to url of my custom ribbon action on a list

```
    javascript:   
//it doesn't work
document.writeln('<script src="http://w50018003l/Style Library/js/jquery211.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'); 
var viewName = $(".s4-titletext h2 span span a span:first").html();
alert(viewName); 
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var lists = web.get_lists();
var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList(); 
var list = lists.getById(listId);
var viewcollection = list.get_views();
var view = list.get_views().getByTitle("All Items");
var vf = [];
var viewFields = view.get_viewFields();
context.load(viewFields);
context.load(viewFields);
context.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnFailure);
function OnSuccess(){
    var e = viewFields.getEnumerator(); 
    while (e.moveNext()) {
        var fieldName = e.get_current();
        vf.push(fieldName);
        var listField = vf.join();
    }
    var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(); 
    var items = [];
    for (var i in selectedItems) {
        var id = selectedItems[i].id;
        alert(id);
        var item = list.getItemById(id);
        items.push(item);
        for(var x=0;x<vf.length;x++){
            context.load(item, vf[x]);
        }
    }
    context.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccessLoadItem,OnFailureLoadItem);
    function OnSuccessLoadItem(){
        var fileExport = "data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,";
        var csv = "";
        for(var x=0;x<vf.length;x++){
            csv+=vf[x]+";";
        }
        csv+="\n";
        for(var cpt=0;cpt<items.length;cpt++){
            for(var x=0;x<vf.length;x++){
                var value = items[cpt].get_item(vf[x]);
                if(value == null){
                    csv+=";";
                }
                else
                {
                    var conditional = typeof value.get_lookupId === 'function';
                    if(conditional){
                    var item_requester_name = value.get_lookupValue(); 
                    var item_requester_id = value.get_lookupId();
                    csv+=item_requester_name+";";
                    }
                    else{
                        csv+=items[cpt].get_item(vf[x])+";";
                    }
                }
            }
            csv+="\n";
        }
        window.open(fileExport+ encodeURIComponent(csv));
    }
    function OnFailureLoadItem(){
    alert("failure loadItem");
    }
}
function OnFailure(){
    alert("failure viewfields");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ribbon should already contain this information.
You can get the view name like this:

```
SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance().getPageComponentById('WebPartWPQ2')._data.ViewName
```

`_data` property contains all kinds of fun stuff.